# Spring Boot Controller to handle all requests for preprocessing before forwarding to appropriate Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I have a series of Rest API Controllers in my Spring boot application with Request Mappings that match certain URLs.
I need to change my implementation to always make sure that a specific custom header is in place for all requests. If header is not there I want to fail the request. If it is I want to forward to the appropriate controller which would be the same as my current implementation.

Is there a way to do this in Spring Boot without modifying my existing controllers at all? Could I try to use something like Spring Security, even though my header is not related to security at all?

Thank you.

Comment: Please try using an interceptor. That is, implement a HandlerInterceptor interface. The link might help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm

Comment: Use filter with generic url pattern. It filter traffic on controller.

Comment: Thank you both. I will investigate the usages of both intereceptors and fiters and figure out the best one for my needs. Sorry I do not have enough reputation to upvote your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web MVC defines an abstraction called "HandlerInterceptor" and its no-op implementation `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`

So you can register the bean that looks like this:

```
@Component
public class RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // check the headers, extract them from request, whatever
        return true; // if you want to proceed to controller
        return false;// otherwise :)
    }
}
```

This will instruct spring mvc to call the method before the flow gets to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) as a `@Service`.

```java
@Service
@NoArgsConstructor @Log4j2
public class FilterImpl implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request.getHeader("required-header-name") != null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            log.info("Rejected {}", request);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```